# Using RemoveAll in a list of objects in C# not removing items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Messages. I want to go through the list and do the following:

1. if SenderID=100, then set the ShowInSenderInbox and ShowInSenderOutbox values to Zero.
2. If ReceiverID=100, then set the ShowInReceiverInbox value set to zero.
   Once the above 2 conditions are met, then I want to check the following:
3. If ShowInSenderInbox == 0 && ShowInSenderOutbox == 0 && ShowInReceiverInbox == 0
                              Then Remove this item from the list.

Currently, my code sets the values of ShowInSenderInbox, ShowInSenderOutbox and ShowInReceiverInbox to zero accordingly. It doesn’t however remove the item that matches condition 3 from the list.

Here is the full code:

```
public class Message
{
   public int MessageID { get; set; }
   public int SenderID { get; set; }
   public int ReceiverID { get; set; }
   public int ShowInSenderInbox { get; set; }
   public int ShowInSenderOutbox { get; set; }
   public int ShowInReceiverInbox { get; set; }
}

public bool GetItem(Message I)
{           
   if (I.SenderID == 100)
   {
      I.ShowInSenderInbox = 0;
      I.ShowInSenderOutbox = 0;
   }
   else if (I.ReceiverID == 100)
   {
      I.ShowInReceiverInbox = 0;
   }

   if (I.ShowInSenderInbox == 0 && I.ShowInSenderOutbox == 0 && I.ShowInReceiverInbox == 0)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }                             
}


List<Message> messages = new List<Message>() {
    new Message { MessageID=1, SenderID=100, ReceiverID=200, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=1, ShowInReceiverInbox=1 },
    new Message { MessageID=2, SenderID=101, ReceiverID=300, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=1, ShowInReceiverInbox=1 },
    new Message { MessageID=3, SenderID=102, ReceiverID=100, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=0, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 },
    new Message { MessageID=4, SenderID=100, ReceiverID=101, ShowInSenderInbox=0, ShowInSenderOutbox=1, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 },
    new Message { MessageID=5, SenderID=200, ReceiverID=300, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=0, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 },
    new Message { MessageID=9, SenderID=100, ReceiverID=400, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=1, ShowInReceiverInbox=1 },
    new Message { MessageID=11, SenderID=400, ReceiverID=100, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=1, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 },
    new Message { MessageID=21, SenderID=80, ReceiverID=150, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=0, ShowInReceiverInbox=1 },
    new Message { MessageID=23, SenderID=100, ReceiverID=300, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=1, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 },
    new Message { MessageID=28, SenderID=50, ReceiverID=90, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=0, ShowInReceiverInbox=1 },
    new Message { MessageID=29, SenderID=100, ReceiverID=900, ShowInSenderInbox=1, ShowInSenderOutbox=1, ShowInReceiverInbox=1 },
    new Message { MessageID=22, SenderID=500, ReceiverID=900, ShowInSenderInbox=0, ShowInSenderOutbox=0, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 },
    new Message { MessageID=39, SenderID=409, ReceiverID=500, ShowInSenderInbox=0, ShowInSenderOutbox=0, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 },
    new Message { MessageID=41, SenderID=105, ReceiverID=900, ShowInSenderInbox=0, ShowInSenderOutbox=0, ShowInReceiverInbox=0 }
 };

( from item in messages
  where item.SenderID == 100 || item.ReceiverID == 100
  select item )
               .ToList()
               .RemoveAll( I => GetItem(I) );
```

http://www.geocities.ws/sonnyk2015/dosscreen2.png

Comment: You're not modifying the original list, you're (potentially) modifying a completely different list.

Comment: What do you mean by the 2 conditions above are met? Which 2 conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line also :

```
messages.RemoveAll(i => i.ShowInSenderInbox == 0 && i.ShowInSenderOutbox == 0 && i.ShowInReceiverInbox == 0);
```

Comment: Thank you @Koder101. I will do that.